# How to configure create-react-app with webpack and how it is running test?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to play with create-react-app, after doing this, I found the following

1) How it is running test? which test framework it is using?
2) there is no webpack.conf.js, although webpack is used?

any other framework I could use beyond create-react-app, I have a feeling it is not easy to use?

Answer (score 1):

create-react-app is just zero-configuration setup utility that uses [`react-scripts` boilerplate](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts) internally. Can also be switched to custom boilerplate with `--scripts-version` option, e.g. [TypeScript setup](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript):

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

As create-react-app description says,

> You can “eject” to a custom setup at any time. Run a single command, and all the configuration and build dependencies will be moved directly into your project, so you can pick up right where you left off.

This can be done with [`npm run eject` application script](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template#npm-run-eject):

> Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!
>
> If you aren’t satisfied with the build tool and configuration choices, you can eject at any time. This command will remove the single build dependency from your project.
>
> Instead, it will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. All of the commands except eject will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point you’re on your own.
>
> You don’t have to ever use eject. The curated feature set is suitable for small and middle deployments, and you shouldn’t feel obligated to use this feature. However we understand that this tool wouldn’t be useful if you couldn’t customize it when you are ready for it.

create-react-app [uses Jest testing framework](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/template#running-tests) which was developed by Facebook, no wonder.